# MVC 4.0 Razor : Better way to set textboxfor and other controls using json?

Tags: ajax, json, post, razor, model-view-controller

OK, so day in and day out I do the same send a value to the controller get json back and set each and every textboxfor / all controls line by line... is there a better way?

I'm doing the typical:

```
 $("#cboUsers").change(function () {

            $.post('../Home/GetDetails', { id: $(this).val() }).done(function (data)
            {                
                $('#FirstName').val(data.Users.FirstName);
                //I wonder if I have to set each textbox/control individually?
            });
        });
```

to a controller:

```
 [HttpPost]<br>
        public ActionResult GetDetails(int id)<br>
        {
            <br>SomeModel Model = new SomeModel();

            Model.Users = m.Users.Where(w => w.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            return Json(Model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
        }
```

it would be great if I didn't have to tell each control "you now have a value"..
I should state that all the code I provided works. I get the value back I expect and the textbox populates with the selected User's first name as desired. But it's tedious setting each textbox to the json's response.

thanks in advanced